# Template from scratch: Sidebars not showing widget

Tags: plugins, php, themes, widgets, sidebar

I have an issue wherein i have a plugin ([newsletter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter/)) which has a widget whereby users can (usually) subscribe to a newsletter and other functionality.

But i digress.

I have been trying to create my own wordpress template solely for personal-use. The following is the code I've accumulated in progression to having a functional sidebar, but so far, un-successful. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

**index.php**

```
<div id="content" class="alignCenter">  
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
    <?php the_content(); ?>  
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?> 
</div>  

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php /**  * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.  *  */
 function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(        'name' => 'Home right sidebar',         'id' =>
 'home_right_1',

    'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
    ?>
```

**Sidebar.php (taken from twentyfourtine theme )**

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the main widget area
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
?>
<div id="secondary">
    <?php
        $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        if ( ! empty ( $description ) ) :
    ?>
    <h2 class="site-description"><?php echo esc_html( $description ); ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary' ) ) : ?>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navigation site-navigation secondary-navigation">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="primary-sidebar" class="primary-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [`is_active_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar) and [`dynamic_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) the argument needs to match the id of a registered sidebar in your theme. In your case that is going to be `home_right_1` not `sidebar-1` as in the code you copied.

Technically, the sidebar name should also work in both and the sidebar index number should work with `is_active_sidebar` but I vaguely recall having trouble getting the name to work correctly, so be aware.